# What's the structure of the group of units of $O_K$ where $K = Q[x]/(x^n-c)$ such as $x^n - c$ is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Premise:
I don't fully understand the Dirchlet unit Theorem and I was wondering about the units of the group of integers over an extension $K$. More precisely the following question:

> What's the structure of the group of units of $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathcal{O} \cap K$ (where $\mathcal{O}$ is the ring of algebraic integers) and $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^n-c)$ such as $x^n - c$ is irreducible and $c \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$?

I thought that the group of units $\mathcal{O}^\times_K$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}^{(n-1)/2} \times T$ when $n$ is odd and $\mathbb{Z}^{n/2} \times T$ when $n$ is even, for some cyclic finite group $T$.
Since on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem):

> in other words, if $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $r_1$ is the number of real roots and $2r_2$ is the number of non-real complex roots of $f$ (which come in complex conjugate pairs);

when in my case $f = x^n - c$ then the solutions are $\{\theta \xi^i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$  where $\theta = \sqrt[n]{c}$
and $\xi^i$ are the roots of $x^n - 1 = 0$. Therefore I have $2r_2 = n-2$ complex solutions and $r_1 = 2$ real solutions for $n$ even and $2r_2 = n-1$, $r_1 = 1$ for $n$ odd. From which follows the conclusion I made above.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.